# validate date in an ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#

I want to check my date input value on server side.

Code:

```
public class DateAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        DateTime date;
        string str = value.ToString();

        if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(str, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

but it always `FALSE` for object values like `21.11.2011 0:00:00`

I can't to understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"mm" is a 2-digit minute.
"MM" is a 2-digit month

If you want July to parse from "07", use "MM". On the other hand, if you want to parse "7" to July, use "M".
Here's the [huge list of formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

EDIT:
Using [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) to parse with a format string:

```cs
string dateString = "21.12.1985 3:12:15";
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString,"d.M.yyyy h:mm:ss",null,DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
    Console.WriteLine(date);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid date");
```

Comment: You need `MM` not `mm`, `MM` is month while `mm` is minute.

Thanks, you are right, but dd.MM.yyyy doesn't work too (

Comment: You need to use `TryParseExact`

Comment: Okay, modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need `MM` not `mm`, `MM` is month while `mm` is minute.

Comment: You need `MM` not `mm`, `MM` is month while `mm` is minute.

Thanks, you are right, but dd.MM.yyyy doesn't work too (

Comment: It's possible the time part is messing it up. Try yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss ?

Comment: @YuriyMayorov: I removed the time element and your code returned true. With the time, I get false. ???

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap it around a try-catch statement and try to use Parse method on it. Since your current code doesn't actually return a particular formatted string, just whether it's valid or not I would do the following below.  DateTime are just long ticks away from a particular date/time, so the format doesn't matter.  From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx we can see that there are only two-exceptions it'll throw, so just take these two exceptions into account and you can add code accordingly.

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(value.ToString());
            return true;
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            // value is null so not a valid string
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            //not a valid string
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```